# SQL Group By COUNT in two

Tags: sql, sql-server

In a certain table, I'm trying to get the `CCID`s that have rows with a `TypeID`, and no rows of any other `TypeID`.  The following SQL query seems incorrect

```
SELECT
  T1.CCID,
  T1.TrCnt AS OurTypeCnt,
  T2.TrCnt AS NotOurTypeCnt
FROM (SELECT
       CCID,
       COUNT(CCID) AS TrCnt
     FROM CCsTransactions
     WHERE TypeID = 5
     GROUP BY CCID) T1,
     (SELECT
       CCID,
       COUNT(CCID) AS TrCnt
     FROM CCsTransactions
     WHERE TypeID <> 5
     GROUP BY CCID) T2
WHERE ((T1.TrCnt >= 1)
AND (T2.TrCnt < 1))
```

It returns empty because the results seem to be joining funny (with no 0 values in the `TrCnts`).

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Ok... I'll try to figure out how to create a fiddle next time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You access the same table twice with different WHERE-conditions. This can be replaced by CASE:

```
SELECT CCID, 
   COUNT(CASE WHEN TypeID = 5 THEN CCID END) as OurTypeCnt,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN TypeID <> 5 THEN CCID END) as NotOurTypeCnt
FROM CCsTransactions 
GROUP BY CCID
HAVING ((OurTypeCnt >= 1) AND (NotOurTypeCnt < 1))
```

Comment: MSSQL doesn't seem to like the "HAVING ((OurTypeCnt >= 1) AND (NotOurTypeCnt < 1))"

but without it returns a list that I can search through.  Thanks!!

Comment: @Mark, you can use `HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN TypeID = 5 THEN CCID END) >= 1 AND COUNT(CASE WHEN TypeID <> 5 THEN CCID END) < 1` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You complete query can be written as:

```
select ccid
from CCsTransactions
group by ccid
having sum(case when TypeId = 5 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when TypeId <> 5 then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Or, a simpler way is:

```
select ccid
from CCsTransactions
group by ccid
having max(TypeId) = 5 and min(TypeId) = 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way you can achieve your results:

```
WITH HasTheType
AS (SELECT
  CCID
FROM CCsTransactions
WHERE TypeID = 5
GROUP BY CCID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 0),
OtherTypes
AS (SELECT
  CCID
FROM CCsTransactions
WHERE TypeID <> 5
GROUP BY CCID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 0)

SELECT
  T.CCID
FROM HasTheType T
LEFT JOIN OtherTypes O
  ON T.CCID = O.CCID
WHERE O.CCID IS NULL
```